# AWK split file every 50 ocurrences of a string

Tags: awk

I have a beginner question about awk.

I am using the line below to split a file into c files, using 'MATCH' as my delimiter.

`awk 'BEGIN{flag=0} /MATCH/{flag++;next} {print $0 > (flag ".txt")}' file`

My file is very long, but it has the form shown below:

```
MATCH
a
b
c
d
MATCH
a
b
```

I want to have the above awk line split my file every 50 'MATCH' ocurrences. The current command creates a new file for each 'MATCH' ocurrence. I am sure there is a simple way to achieve this, but I have not figured it out yet. I have tried using the line below with no luck.

`awk 'BEGIN{flag=0} /MATCH/{flag++ == 50;next} {print $0 > (flag ".txt")}' file`

I appreciate the help and guidance.

Comment: to clarify, is file `1.txt` intended to hold 50 blocks of a, b, c, d content? I may have misunderstood.

Comment: Yes. I think you understood it correctly.

Comment: should the output files include the `MATCH` lines?

Answer (score 3):

Untested, using any awk:

```
awk '
    /MATCH/ && ( ( (++matchCnt) % 50 ) == 1 ) {
        close(out)
        out = (++outCnt) ".txt"
    }
    { print > out }
' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- the number of lines in a `MATCH` block are not known beforehand
- the number of lines in a `MATCH` block could vary
- the `MATCH` lines are to be copied to the output files

Sample input with 9 `MATCH` blocks:

```
$ cat file
MATCH
1.1
1.2
MATCH
2.1
2.2
MATCH
3.1
3.2
MATCH
4.1
4.2
MATCH
5.1
5.2
MATCH
6.1
6.2
MATCH
7.1
7.2
MATCH
8.1
8.2
MATCH
9.1
9.2
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v blkcnt=3 '                             # for OP case set blkcnt=50
BEGIN   { outfile= ++fcnt ".txt" }
/MATCH/ { if (++matchcnt > blkcnt) {
             close(outfile)
             outfile= ++fcnt ".txt"
             matchcnt=1
          }
       #  next                                # uncomment if the "MATCH" lines are *NOT* to be copied to the output files
        }
        { print $0 > outfile }
'  file
```

For `blkcnt=3` this generates:

```
$ head -40 {1..3}.txt
==> 1.txt <==
MATCH
1.1
1.2
MATCH
2.1
2.2
MATCH
3.1
3.2

==> 2.txt <==
MATCH
4.1
4.2
MATCH
5.1
5.2
MATCH
6.1
6.2

==> 3.txt <==
MATCH
7.1
7.2
MATCH
8.1
8.2
MATCH
9.1
9.2
```

For `blkcnt=4` this generates:

```
$ head -40 {1..3}.txt
==> 1.txt <==
MATCH
1.1
1.2
MATCH
2.1
2.2
MATCH
3.1
3.2
MATCH
4.1
4.2

==> 2.txt <==
MATCH
5.1
5.2
MATCH
6.1
6.2
MATCH
7.1
7.2
MATCH
8.1
8.2

==> 3.txt <==
MATCH
9.1
9.2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, the first 50 blocks of a,b,c,d lines should be written to `1.txt`, the next 50 to `2.txt` and so on.

This can be achieved by building the filename from the integer value of `(flag/50)` and adding 1 to it (assuming you want the file series to being with 1 and not 0).

The BEGIN block can be removed as variables are set to 0 when first created if no value is given and they are used numerically.

Thus the following should achieve the desired output:

```
awk '/MATCH/{flag++;next} {print $0 >(int(flag/50)+1 ".txt")}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

so while this isn't a complete solution, it does showcase how to capture each group of rows with each `"MATCH"`, so once you count off every 50, then print them out in one shot, bearing in mind one needs to trim out the tail `"MATCH"` and save it for the next round

```
nice jot 53 | mawk 'NR % 6 != 1 || ($!NF = "MATCH")^_' |
```

> ```
> mawk '{ printf(" :: input row(s) = %8u\n ::" \
>                   " output row # = %8u\n "   \
>                "-------------------\n %s%s " \
>                 "----END-NEW-ROW----\n\n", NF^!!NF, NR, $!(NF = NF), ORS) 
>
> }' RS='(^)?MATCH\r?\n' ORS='MATCH\n' FS='\n' OFS='\f'
> ```

```
 :: input row(s) =        1
 :: output row # =        1
 -------------------
 MATCH
 ----END-NEW-ROW----

 :: input row(s) =        6
 :: output row # =        2
 -------------------
 2
  3
   4
    5
     6
      MATCH
 ----END-NEW-ROW----

 :: input row(s) =        6
 :: output row # =        3
 -------------------
 8
  9
   10
     11
       12
         MATCH
 ----END-NEW-ROW----

 :: input row(s) =        6
 :: output row # =        4
 -------------------
 14
   15
     16
       17
         18
           MATCH
 ----END-NEW-ROW----

 :: input row(s) =        6
 :: output row # =        5
 -------------------
 20
   21
     22
       23
         24
           MATCH
 ----END-NEW-ROW----

 :: input row(s) =        6
 :: output row # =        6
 -------------------
 26
   27
     28
       29
         30
           MATCH
 ----END-NEW-ROW----

 :: input row(s) =        6
 :: output row # =        7
 -------------------
 32
   33
     34
       35
         36
           MATCH
 ----END-NEW-ROW----

 :: input row(s) =        6
 :: output row # =        8
 -------------------
 38
   39
     40
       41
         42
           MATCH
 ----END-NEW-ROW----

 :: input row(s) =        6
 :: output row # =        9
 -------------------
 44
   45
     46
       47
         48
           MATCH
 ----END-NEW-ROW----

 :: input row(s) =        5
 :: output row # =       10
 -------------------
 50
   51
     52
       53
         MATCH
 ----END-NEW-ROW----
```